# How do i fix Lmonth loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have an Lmonth Loop code that searches though a list of dates to find jobs that were ordered in january (1) for example and copy&pastes those into a new sheet.

The code runs fine but when it gets to then end it flags a @debug error 13'

If i disable the line the code does not function but i cannot work out what is broken.

```
Sub Search_Month()

    Dim datasheet As Worksheet
    Set datasheet = Sheet2
    Dim Mreport As Worksheet
    Set Mreport = Sheet9

    Dim Lmonth As Integer
    Search = Range("m4").Value

    Dim i As Integer

    Mreport.Unprotect Password:=rapid1

    Mreport.Range("a2:a300").ClearContents

    datasheet.Activate

    For i = 7 To 5000

        Lmonth = Month(Cells(i, 6))

        If Lmonth = Search Then

            Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i + 3, 2)).Copy
            Mreport.Activate
            Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            datasheet.Activate

        End If

    Next i

    Mreport.Activate

    Mreport.Protect Password:=rapid1

    MsgBox "End of Month Report Updated"

End Sub
```

The line that flags is Lmonth = Month(Cells(i, 6)) but i dont know why.

All the results the macro finds are correct, just the error at the end is annoying. I think its saying 'the next search line does not show lmonth=1 so i cant run the code anymore so it must be broken"

Comment: What is the value of `i` and the contents of `Cells(i,6)` when it errors?

Comment: The value of i varies but will be when the date that is being searched through is no longer equal to the month number being looked for. Eg if i'm searching for all the jobs in january and i82 is 01/02/19 (cells(1,6) then it will error at row 82.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error with the information and code you have provided. If you do not find another solution, I suggest you upload a workbook (with sensitive information removed) that demonstrates the problem to some sharing site (eg dropbox, onedrive) and then post a link here.

Answer (score 0):

Debug error 13 is a type mismatch. So the function "Month" is given a value, that cannot be processed.

See [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/month-function) for reference. It needs to be a date.

Your main problem seems the fact, that you just go from line 7 to 5000 without even checking if there is any content. I don't think you can trust the fact, that there are always 4993 entries in the table.

So I recomment to change the loop to something like `For i = 7 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count`. Also you can check the datatype before using "Month()" with the "[IsDate](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isdate-function)"-function if you are unsure.

Comment: the only reason i used 7-5000 was because i couldn't get the usedrange coding to work and i knew 5000 was a safe number (each job takes 4 rows) as 1200 or so jobs in a year is about the max we receive. My problem is i have very little experience with VBA so my codes are often simple and longwinded.

Comment: You should also check a tutorial about [Data Validation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/apply-data-validation-to-cells-29fecbcc-d1b9-42c1-9d76-eff3ce5f7249) - so wrong dates are a thing of the past.

Answer (score 0):

## Copy Monthly

- I've changed the variable `rapid1` to a string. You might want to
  change this to make the code work.
- Although implementing constants (change only once and change quickly
  'in one place' (at the beginning)) and naming them appropriately is
  probably increasing readability for others (and for you, after a
  while), it might not be so while developing. Therefore I've included
  the **No Constants Version** below the **Main Version**.

### Main Version

```
Sub Search_Month()

    ' Data
    Const cSearch As String = "M4"  ' Search Value Cell Range
    Const cFRD As Long = 7          ' First Row Number
    Const cOffset As String = 3     ' Copy Row Offset
    Const cCol As Variant = "F"     ' Search Column Letter/Number
    Const cCopy As Variant = "B"    ' Copy Column Letter/Number
    ' Report
    Const cFRR As Long = 2          ' First Row Number
    Const cWrite As Variant = "A"   ' Write Column Letter/Number
    ' Data
    Dim datasheet As Worksheet  ' Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range            ' Last Cell Range
    Dim Search As Long          ' Search Month
    Dim vntMonth As Variant     ' Current Month
    Dim i As Long               ' Row Counter
    ' Report
    Dim Mreport As Worksheet    ' Worksheet
    Dim FER As Long             ' First Empty Row

    ' Create References to Worksheets
    Set datasheet = Sheet2
    Set Mreport = Sheet9

    ' Speed up
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With
    On Error GoTo ProcedureExit

    ' In Data Worksheet
    With datasheet

        ' Assign value from Search Value Cell Range to Search Month.
        Search = .Range(cSearch).Value

        ' In Search Column
        With .Columns(cCol)
            ' Calculate Last Cell Range in Search Column.
            Set rng = .Find("*", , xlFormulas, xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
        End With

        If rng Is Nothing Then ' No data in column (Highly unlikely).
            MsgBox "No Data in column '" _
                    & Split(.Cells(1, cCol).Address, "$")(1) & "'."
            GoTo ProcedureExit
        End If

        ' In Report Worksheet
        With Mreport
            .Unprotect Password:="rapid1"
            ' Clear contents from First Row to bottom cell of Write Column.
            .Cells(cFRR, cWrite).Resize(.Rows.Count - cFRR + 1).ClearContents
            ' Write First Row Number to First Empty Row.
            FER = cFRR
        End With

        ' Loop through cells of Data Worksheet.
        For i = cFRD To rng.Row
            ' Write value of current cell to Current Month.
            vntMonth = .Cells(i, cCol)
            ' Check if Current Month is a date or can be converted to a date.
            If IsDate(vntMonth) Then
                ' Check if month of current cell value is equal to Current Month.
                If Month(vntMonth) = Search Then
                    ' Write data from Data Worksheet to Report Worksheet.
                    Mreport.Cells(FER, cWrite).Resize(cOffset) = _
                            .Cells(i, cCopy).Resize(cOffset).Value
                    FER = FER + cOffset
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With

    ' In Report Worksheet
    With Mreport
        .Protect Password:="rapid1"
        MsgBox "End of Month Report Updated"
    End With

ProcedureExit:

    ' Speed down
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub
```

### No Constants Version

```
Sub Search_Month_No_Constants()

    ' Data
    Dim datasheet As Worksheet  ' Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range            ' Last Cell Range
    Dim Search As Long          ' Search Month
    Dim vntMonth As Variant     ' Current Month
    Dim i As Long               ' Row Counter
    ' Report
    Dim Mreport As Worksheet    ' Worksheet
    Dim FER As Long             ' First Empty Row

    ' Create References to Worksheets
    Set datasheet = Sheet2
    Set Mreport = Sheet9

    ' Speed up
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With
    On Error GoTo ProcedureExit

    ' In Data Worksheet
    With datasheet

        ' Assign value from Search Value Cell Range to Search Month.
        Search = .Range("M4").Value

        ' In Search Column
        With .Columns("F")
            ' Calculate Last Cell Range in Search Column.
            Set rng = .Find("*", , xlFormulas, xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
        End With

        If rng Is Nothing Then ' No data in column (Highly unlikely).
            MsgBox "No Data in column 'F'." _
            GoTo ProcedureExit
        End If

        ' In Report Worksheet
        With Mreport
            .Unprotect Password:="rapid1"
            ' Clear contents from First Row to bottom cell of Write Column.
            .Cells(2, "A").Resize(.Rows.Count - 2 + 1).ClearContents
            ' Write First Row Number to First Empty Row.
            FER = 2
        End With

        ' Loop through cells of Data Worksheet.
        For i = 7 To rng.Row
            ' Write value of current cell to Current Month.
            vntMonth = .Cells(i, "F")
            ' Check if Current Month is a date or can be converted to a date.
            If IsDate(vntMonth) Then
                ' Check if month of current cell value is equal to Current Month.
                If Month(vntMonth) = Search Then
                    ' Write data from Data Worksheet to Report Worksheet.
                    Mreport.Cells(FER, "A").Resize(3) = _
                            .Cells(i, "B").Resize(3).Value
                    FER = FER + 3
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With

    ' In Report Worksheet
    With Mreport
        .Protect Password:="rapid1"
        MsgBox "End of Month Report Updated"
    End With

ProcedureExit:

    ' Speed down
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

well this is embarrassing...

I tried many of your options above to no avail, I then went to paste something into my code and it pasted a job number which i thought was odd, but was actually the job no of where the code broke down. So i went to look at this field and found i had entered the date for that field as 07/02/19/, the final forward breaker was throwing a code error.

Deleted the / and re run the code and it worked perfectly with no debug error.

Thanks everyone for your help and advice, I will use your coding and feedback to improve this code and many more in the future

Many thanks again!

## rookieerror!